# Check values of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following as a results of a `collect`

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([16660,23517,23518,10,1,0])
```

How do I pull info from this Array ?
I need to check if any of the values is a `0`

Comment: Row contains multiple columns which column do you want to check that condition ???

Comment: @Srinivas I want to check if any of them contains a zero, editing the question to make this more clear

Comment: without ```collect``` you can get same result?

Comment: @Srinivas That is the only row of a dataframe. I just need to check if the value in any of the columns is a zero. I thought a collect would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val df = Seq((1,2,3,4,5),(1,0,3,4,5),(1,2,3,4,0)).toDF()
df.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4| _5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
|  1|  0|  3|  4|  5|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+


val arr = df.collect() 
// array with boolens indicating if 0 exist in each column
val res =  Array.fill(arr(0).length)(false) 
// convert Array[Row] to Array[Array[Int]]
val arr2 = for( j <- 0 until arr.length) yield {for (i <- 0 until arr(j).length) yield {(arr(j).getInt(i))}} 
arr2.foreach(s=>for(i <- 0 until s.length) if(s(i)==0) res(i)=true)
```

output:

```
res: Array[Boolean] = Array(false, true, false, false, true)
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Thank you !